# Is "algebraic system" the same as "algebraic structure"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

1.

algebraic system | planetmath.org:

http://planetmath.org/algebraicsystem

It seems that algebraic system is only a set on which some operations are defined.
Is it necessary that some additional conditions hold?
like commutativity, associativity.....?

2.

Elements of Modern Algebra By Linda Gilbert
3.1
p.141

http://tinyurl.com/q5qvgff

It seems say "algebraic system" and "algebraic structure" are the same.

I am confused.....

Comment: In general, they mean the same, as is written in the book you linked. No conditions such as associativity are needed in the definition of algebraic structure/system. For example, an algebraic structure/system with a unique binary operation which is associative and has a bilateral unit and bilateral inverses is a group. An algebraic structure/system with a unique associative binary operation is a magma, etc... Note, however, that some other authors may make a distinction between structure and system (e.g. a system consists of a class of certain structures).

Comment: 3.

Linear Algebra 4th edition 
Friedberg Insel Spence 

1.2 P.6

http://imgur.com/TMvQzYD

Do the authors make a distinction between structure and system?

Thanks

Comment: There's also no distinction. In general, I believe, it is safe to assume they mean the same.

Comment: It depends on the context, too. For example, an [Euler system](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11404/what-is-an-euler-system-and-the-motivation-for-it) is only a collection (of compatible elements of Galois cohomology groups indexed by fields). So an Euler system is not an algebraic structure, but perhaps an algebraic system.

Answer (score 0):

They're the same. $\;\!\;\!\;\!\;\!$

> It seems that algebraic system is only a set on which some operations
>   are defined. Is it necessary that some additional conditions hold?
>   like commutativity, associativity.....?

No additional assumptions are required.